# Understanding Adruino Binary to Decimal Conversations

Tags: arduino, type-conversion

I was looking at some code today for integrating a real time clock with an arduino and it had some binary to decimal (and vice versa) that I don't fully understand.

The code in question is below:

```
byte decToBcd(byte val)
{
  return ( (val/10*16) + (val%10) );
}

byte bcdToDec(byte val)
{
  return ( (val/16*10) + (val%16) );
}

ex: decToBcd(12);
```

I really fail to grasp how this works. I am not sure I understand the math, or if some sort of assumptions are being taken advantage of.

Would someone mind explaining how exactly the math and data types below are supposed to work? If possible touching on why the value "16" is used in the conversions instead of "8" when we are supposed to be working with a byte value.

For context, the full code can be found here: http://www.codingcolor.com/microcontrollers/an-arduino-lcd-clock-using-a-chronodot-rtc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key hint here is BCD - [Binary-coded decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) - in the function name. In BCD each decimal digit is represented by four bits (half of a byte). As a result the maximum (decimal) number you can store using BCD notation is 99 - 9 in the upper nibble (half of the byte) and 9 in the lower nibble. 
Let's take a look at number 12 as an example. Number 12 looks as follows in the binary notation:

```
12 = %00001010
```

However in BCD it looks as follows:

```
12 = %00010010
```

because

```
0001 0010
   1    2
```

Now if you look at the `decToBcd` function `val%10` is responsible for calculating the value of the ones place (i.e. the last digit). Since this goes to the lower part of the byte we don't need to do anything special here. `val/10*16` first calculates the value of the tens place - `val/10`. However since the value has to go to the upper half of the byte it needs to be shifted up by four bits - hence `*16`. Another (in my opinion more readable) way of writing this function would be:

```
((val / 10) << 4) | (val % 10)
```

The `bcdToDec` does the reverse conversion.

Comment: thanks, makes sense to me! Though I wonder though, based on this code, how would someone extract the year from this RTC, if you can only get digits from 0-99? Would 2014 be returned as two binary coded decimals?

Comment: I don't look at the code so I don't know how they are using these functions. I think they have to store year in short (16-bit) variable and then you can convert it to two bcd bytes by calling the method twice - once for centuries (year / 100) and once for years (year % 100)

Answer (score 0):

RTC usually stores Year in 1 byte as 2 digits only, i.e: 2014 is 14.
And some of them stores it as a number from the year 1970 so 2014 = 44.
So maximum it can hold is 99 in both cases.